# Scrapy follow vs follow_all

Tags: python, scrapy

From the tutorial of scrapy,there is an example: **QuotesSpider**.
When following link,

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

This code will fetch all pages.
Alternatively,

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)

        yield from response.follow_all(css='li.next a', callback=self.parse)
        # or equivalently
        # urls = response.css("li.next a")
        # yield from response.follow_all(urls=urls, callback=self.parse)
```

But when I replace `yield from response.follow_all(css='li.next a', callback=self.parse)` with `yield response.follow(css='li.next a', callback=self.parse)`, it only fetch page 1. Since `response.css("li.next a")` return at most one selector, I expect it will also fetch all pages in latter case. Why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The example is about a case where only 1 next page is expected. `follow_all` can be used there to make your code shorter, but it can be misleading as you only expect to follow 1 next page. If you expect multiple requests, a single `yield` (not followed by `from` or in a loop) will never work.

Comment: @Gallaecio I thought if I use `yield response.follow(css='li.next a', callback=self.parse)`, next_page will call `parse` again when new request is done, then execute `yield response.follow(css='li.next a', callback=self.parse)` again until next page is `None`. Here multiple requests can be multiple links in one page or one link in many pages?

Comment: Hmm… I thought the issue was something else. What you describe should indeed be happening. Do the logs show anything interesting? Do they state that page 2 is being crawled?

Answer (score 0):

A little late:

It is because the `response.follow()` does not accept css as parameter, so the code only fetches the page 1 and then fails. The response you are getting is a `TextResponse` class. When you pass `response.follow_all(css=...`, what is happening is that the class is executing the method `self.css(css)` which returns an iterable of URLs, which is why it works. With `response.follow()`, there is no such method

You can read more in [TextResponse](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/http/response/text.html#TextResponse)